# GeoWebCache blank tiles

Tags: geowebcache

I'm new with GWC and I'm trying to cache this WMS server [1](http://idecan2.grafcan.es/ServicioWMS/Callejero?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS). I can see layer list from this server on "A list of all the layers and automatic demos" but when I select one PNG from any layer I only see blank tiles.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using GWC within GeoServer? If so can you see your data in the standard layer preview?

Comment: No I´m using standalone GWC. I´m trying only to cache external tiles.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your layers in the geowebcache.xml. Have you changed the url in the tag wmsUrl?
By default this is set to:

```
<wmsUrl>
<string>http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms</string>
</wmsUrl>
```

You should set it, so that it points to your geoserver.